# Ruby on Rails, gem throwing error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails (v. 4.2) deployed on Heroku. I cloned the machine in order to have also a test environment so basically I have two Heroku machines with the same application running.

The problem is that in the test environment some Gem started throwing errors, I did not change any Gem or version.

For example mailchimp throws this error:

```
 ! Unable to load application: Mailchimp::Exception::APIKeyError: Invalid API key format:
 bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma)
 Mailchimp::Exception::APIKeyError: Invalid API key format:
```

Once removed Mailchimp the Gem Plivo started to throws error:

```
 bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma)
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/plivo-0.3.19/lib/plivo.rb:38:in `+'
 ! Unable to load application: TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
 TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

On localhost and the production machine the application works fine, what can be wrong here?

Comment: Did you set the mailchimp API key on the cloned environment?

Comment: You were right, basically I use Figaro to handle all the environment variables and I forgot to run: figaro heroku:set -e production

Comment: Ok cool I added an answer if you don't mind accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have not set the Mail chimp API key appropriately in the environment in question.  Try resetting your environment variables and see if you are still experiencing the issue.